# Vectorising displaced circle in after effects

Tags: adobe-after-effects

By using [this technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4tqbUcN_Hs) with Beam and Displacement Map I created a wavy outlined circle. So it's not just a circle rotating, the generated waves actually move.

[image]

The problem is, I need this circle to be exported in Lottie with Bodymovin, with vectors.

That means that I can't use any effects (except Stroke) and am stuck with shape tools and expressions.

I thought about auto-tracing every single frame in AE, but it creates a bunch of messy masks and Lottie doesn't understand this.

Then I thought about exporting every single frame to png, bulk-tracing it in VectorMagic, and putting all those traced AI files back to AE and giving each file 1 frame, but the bulk-tracing makes some unnecessary shapes on top of the main one and AE doesn't recognize it.

Is there a simpler way to do this effect with vectors using shapes or expressions in AE?

Comment: Why dont you do this ib javascript?